# CakePHP 3 updateAll with alias

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.4

In CakePHP 2 we can use aliases in `updateAll` method, but in CakePHP 3 (tested 3.4.9) cannot using alias?

```
$this->_table->updateAll([
    $this->_table->getAlias() . '.deleted' => Time::now()
], [
    $this->_table->getAlias() . '.' . $this->_table->getPrimaryKey() => $entity->{$this->_table->getPrimaryKey()}
]);
```

If Your table is `products` and alias is `Products` it's works, but doesn't work if Your table is `cart_products` and alias is `CartProducts`

The SQL should looks like:
`UPDATE cart_products AS CartProducts SET... WHERE CartProducts.id = ...`
instead of
`UPDATE cart_products SET... WHERE CartProducts.id = ...`

BTW: code above is from my behavior.

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what _exactly_ you'd expect to happen instead. I guess the problem is that the resulting query will contain aliases in the `UPDATE` clause, but not in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I added SQL code... The SQL looks like `UPDATE cart_products SET ... WHERE CartProducts.id = ...`. There are missing `AS CartProducts`after `cart_products`

Comment: Where do you see that generated SQL? I would expect the `WHERE` clause to not have aliases (for reasons that I can explain in answer later on), and a quick test with 3.4.9 shows exactly that for me, aliases in the `SET` clause, but none in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use aliases in `updateAll()` queries. The `updateAll()` function doesn't support joins, so all fields can be used unaliased.